# Calculate confidence level from a given confidence interval

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, confidence-interval

I'm fairly comfortable calculating the confidence interval. But now I'm seeing a problem where I'm giving a confidence interval $CI(27.6621, 30.3379)$ and I'm requested to calculate the confidence level. I'm also given the sample size $n=85$ and a standard deviation $\sigma=7.5$. I can't find a formula for that, I feel like it's something simple I'm not seeing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there is information missing. What parameter (and from what model) are you trying to cover?  Did the interval come from a classic formula for CI's? What is the test statistic? What is the hypothesis test? Is there any assumption of gaussianity? Are you using an asymptotic interval like Wald's CI?

Comment: @RLC I'm not given any other data that I'm aware of.

Comment: @RLC the complete problem reads: 

"When doing a statistical study for the population mean, a sample is taken of size $n=85$ with a population standard deviation of $7.5$. Find the confidence level used to build the following confidence interval: $CI(27.6621, 30.3379)$."

I'm not sure if there's an additional data hidden in the terms that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Rethinking my first comment, there is no strict need for a hypothesis test (but sometimes CI's and HT's are equivalents). I think that the question assumes that the data is gaussian with known sd. So the most natural statistic for the CI is $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu_0)/\sigma_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the data comes from $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with known $\sigma^2$, we have that
$$
\dfrac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)}{\sigma}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1).
$$
If $z_{1-\alpha}$ is such that $P(\mathcal{N}(0,1)\geq z_{\alpha/2})=\alpha/2$, then the CI for $\mu$ is 
$$\left(\bar{X}_n-\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}z_{\alpha/2},\bar{X}_n+\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}z_{\alpha/2}\right).$$
Substract both sides to get that 
$$\dfrac{2\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}z_{\alpha/2}=c,$$
where $c$ is known. In a normal table find the $\alpha$ such that $z_{\alpha/2}=c\sqrt{n}/(2\sigma)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to follow, how is it that $c$ is known? And where would I get one of these normal table?

Comment: I'm assuming in this case $c=30.3379-27.662=2.6759$, in which case I get $z_{1-\alpha}=1.6445$. I googled for "normal table" and got many different ones, using the first found in Wikipedia[1] I get 0.44950, and then I'm assuming I have to multiply by 2 to account for the $\pm$ interval, thus being 0.899, which I can round up to 90%. Is this what you meant?


[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table

Comment: @FernandoGómez You are right on the value of $c$. Note the changes I made to the answer. I recommend you this table https://www.stat.ncsu.edu/people/osborne/courses/xiamen/normal-table.pdf. With this table and the value that you calculated for $z_{\alpha/2}=1.6445$ you get $\alpha/2=0.0505$.

Comment: thank you I think I got it ($1-\alpha = 0.899$).